# JMeter connection refused

Tags: networking, jmeter, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run JMeter on a remote server. 
I'm running JMeter-server on a new VM instance, and the GUI client from my desktop.

I edited the `jmeter.properties` file and inserted the external IP and port of my new VM.

```
# Remote Hosts - comma delimited
remote_hosts=<my external IP>
#remote_hosts=localhost:1099,localhost:2010

# RMI port to be used by the server (must start rmiregistry with same port)
server_port=1099
```

I also enabled that specific port and IP on my firewall.

To test I used curl and got a response immediately:

```
curl <my external IP>:1099
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

When I started the JMeter GUI, I got an exception:

> connection refused to host:<***Internal*** IP of my new VM>

My question is - why is the JMeter GUI trying to reach my internal IP instead of the external IP specified in the properties? How does JMeter know my internal IP? What am I missing? Do I need to configure it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jmeter-server/jmeter-server.bat file uncomment:

> RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=

Comment: I added `RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` on jmeter-server.bat file - still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: ok . figured it out . placed it in jmeter-server file and placed the server's external ip address. now when connecting from the client . i get `jmeter engine error initialization error`

Comment: this is another question. Can you ask another question and accept this answer ? thx

Comment: added new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574133/jmeter-connection-refused-to-host-127-0-1-1