# JMeter: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1

Tags: networking, centos, jmeter

My localhost runs a Jmeter GUI with `./jmeter`

I'm trying to run JMeter on a remote server. I'm running JMeter-server on a new VM instance, and the GUI client from my desktop.
the remote server ip is `148.6.60.8`

I've edited jmeter-server file `RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=148.6.60.8`

When connecting from client I get

```
ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper:  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.testEnded(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper.testEnded(RemoteTestListenerWrapper.java:79)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:228)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:448)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does java rmi keep connecting to 127.0.1.1. When ip is 192.168.X.X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478649/why-does-java-rmi-keep-connecting-to-127-0-1-1-when-ip-is-192-168-x-x)

Comment: Could you please add more details about what you're trying to do? Jmeter really has an option to be run as a client-server application, but it doesn't mean that jmeter client you run with ./jmeter can connect to jmeter-server and you can operate server machine using your client. Vise versa: Jmeter-server is the node that operates multiple jmeter client nodes while running distributed tests. Based on your question, it looks like you just trying to manipulate a jmeter-server instance on your VM by client on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks.  can I mark this question as duplicated? @KirilS.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your client jmeter in user.properties:

> host=148.6.60.8

Otherwise JMeter can't guess that it needs to connect to the remote server on this IP.